# How to create clustered index in MongoDB using .NET driver?

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

I'm unable to find a way to create a clustered index in MongoDB with .NET driver. I've tried with docs, reviewing methods in `Collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync` and in `Database.CreateCollection` without luck. Is it an available feature in MongoDB.Driver 2.19.0?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken - you can have **only 1 clustered index** in the collection, and by default in MongoDB its `_id_` index. If you need one more clustered-like index you can specify `unique` index instead:

```
var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<T>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.field);

CreateIndexOptions options = new()
{
    Unique = true,
    Sparse = true //if field is nullable
};

CreateIndexModel<T> createIndexModel = new(indexKeysDefinition, options);



//to create single index at once
_collection.Indexes.CreateOne(createIndexModel);
//or async version
await _collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(createIndexModel);
```

Comment: But what about if I want to have a compound index as the clustered one, instead of the default _id? Doesn't seems like a supported scenario by the driver..

Comment: You're absolutely right. Currently (2.19.1) only '_id' is supported. You can try it yourself this way (only when creating a new collection, you can't modify existing one):
 `var opt = new CreateCollectionOptions<T>
{
    ClusteredIndex = new ClusteredIndexOptions<T>
    {
        Key= Builders<T>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Name) 
    },
};
`
But you're going to get excption: `MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command create failed: The clusteredIndex option is only supported for key: {_id: 1}.'
 `